# Why is arcpullr pulling an empty RasterBrick from ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: r, rest, geospatial, arcgis, arcpullr

I am having trouble getting raster data in R from the ArcGIS REST API. It is located at the endpoint [https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_service/IMG_VCGI_LIDARNDSM_WM_CACHE_v1/ImageServer](https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_services/IMG_VCGI_LIDARNDSM_WM_CACHE_v1/ImageServer) and I want to fetch just the data for my area of interest. I can successfully load the data in QGIS as a web coverage service using the url "https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/services/EGC_services/IMG_VCGI_LIDARNDSM_WM_CACHE_v1/ImageServer/WCSServer", but want something I can turn into a raster layer or raster brick in R.

I would prefer a high-level method and have tried the `arcpullr` package, using an `sf` polygon object of my area of interest to define the bounding box (`aoi` in the code below, which is a simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field;
Bounding box:  xmin: 499682.2 ymin: 208467.7 xmax: 503271.3 ymax: 212056.7;
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Vermont, 32145). This returns an empty raster brick (all values are NA) in the correct location:

```
endpoint <- "https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_services/IMG_VCGI_LIDARNDSM_WM_CACHE_v1/ImageServer/"
ndsm <- get_image_layer(url = endpoint, sf_object = aoi)
```

I have also tried to construct the request myself based on the [API reference](https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/sdk/rest/index.html#//02ss00000021000000), using various queries, and have only been able to write empty image files (though the server returns status codes of '200'). Here is an example:

```
url <- "https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_services/IMG_VCGI_LIDARNDSM_WM_CACHE_v1/ImageServer/exportImage?f=html&bbox=499682.2,208467.7,503271.3,212056.7&imageSR=32145&bboxSR=32145&format=png"
file = tempfile(fileext = ".png")
httr::GET(url = url, httr::write_disk(file))
```

I would appreciate any ideas for getting `arcpullr` to work, suggestions for other relatively easy approaches, or (as a last resort) resources for learning more about APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is that you are not using the right `crs`. You simply need to convert your `aoi` from `EPSG: 32145` to `EPSG: 3857` (the spatial projection information is provided on the [Service webpage](https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_services/IMG_VCGI_LIDARNDSM_WM_CACHE_v1/ImageServer)).

So, please find below a little reprex.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(arcpullr)

# Creating the aoi in `EPSG: 32145` and converting it into the right crs (i.e. `EPSG: 3857`)
aoi <- st_sf(st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = 499682.2, xmax = 503271.3, ymin = 208467.7, ymax = 212056.7), crs = st_crs(32145)))) %>% 
  st_transform(., st_crs(3857))

# Extracting the raster corresponding to the `aoi`
endpoint <- "https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_services/IMG_VCGI_LIDARNDSM_WM_CACHE_v1/ImageServer/"
ndsm <- get_image_layer(url = endpoint, sf_object = aoi)
```

- Output (the rasterbrick contains the pixel values)

```r
ndsm
#> class      : RasterBrick 
#> dimensions : 400, 400, 160000, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 12.58247, 12.58247  (x, y)
#> extent     : -8071116, -8066083, 5523882, 5528915  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : X_ags_6919e084_8cf5_46f6_b95c_1090872a66d0.1, X_ags_6919e084_8cf5_46f6_b95c_1090872a66d0.2, X_ags_6919e084_8cf5_46f6_b95c_1090872a66d0.3 
#> min values :                                            1,                                           49,                                            0 
#> max values :                                          254,                                          254,                                          149
```

- Visualization

```r
raster::plotRGB(ndsm)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>